# Navigation disappear on small resolutions

Tags: navigation, invisible

So I've been devleoping a website and the problem is when I zoom in 200%+ my navigation icons disappear. I tested on phone to make sure zooming is not the issue. Im trying to make navigation bar responsive.
I can setup online if necessary
Here is my html/css

```
.nav {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 75px;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  border-right: none;
}
.nav ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-right: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 35px;
}
.nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.nav ul li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="home.html">
        <img src="works.png" style='min-width:25%;' border="0" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="about.html">
        <img src="aboutme.png" style='min-width:25%;' border="0" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="services.html">
        <img src="blog.png" style='min-width:25%;' border="0" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="contact.html">
        <img src="kontakt.png" style='min-width:25%;' border="0" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not find any error. can you publish it online and post the link here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, here is the link http://test-sajt.netau.net/ (sorry about the ads, its hostings). I assume I messed up with media query then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution:

```
@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
/*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;  --->> This is causing the problem // either delete it or use it as display:block;

}
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Yeah, it works! The silly thing is that is totally unnecessary lines of codes which I forgot to remove. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie :>